# What does -G do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have searched around the Internet and the Perl doc and can't seem to find the answer.

Help will be appreciated.

EDIT:: He asked me about -G, wrote it down on a piece of paper and when i looked stumped asked me to go read up on the basics.

Comment: I can't find any info about -G either. Can you show us an example?

Comment: Somebody's wires are getting crossed here.

Comment: What was the exact question he asked you?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with JesperE, please show us some code. However, as far as I can tell, this is what's happening:

```
if(-G) {
```

Perl sees this, doesn't recognize `-G`, and so treats it as a string. It becomes:

```
if('-G') {
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if(1) {
```

So as far as I can tell, `if(-G)` does nothing. I've tried using it, and it always seems to return true, which supports my hypothesis. Further support is from the following code (tested on OS X with Perl 5.10.0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = -G;
print "$var\n";
```

Displays no warnings, compiles and runs, and prints simply "-G".

EDIT: Doing a search I should have done much earlier provides the following from Perldoc's [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators) page:

> Unary "-" performs arithmetic negation if the operand is numeric. If the operand is an identifier, a string consisting of a minus sign concatenated with the identifier is returned. Otherwise, if the string starts with a plus or minus, a string starting with the opposite sign is returned. One effect of these rules is that -bareword is equivalent to the string "-bareword". If, however, the string begins with a non-alphabetic character (excluding "+" or "-"), Perl will attempt to convert the string to a numeric and the arithmetic negation is performed. If the string cannot be cleanly converted to a numeric, Perl will give the warning **Argument "the string" isn't numeric in negation (-) at ....**

As stated in the comments, `B::Deparse` appears to show that Perl converts `if(-G)` to `if(-'G')`. However, the documentation (and the behavior with `print()`) are consistent with the documentation, which says that it should convert `if(-G)` to `if('-G')`. This doesn't change the result of the program either way.

However, subtle typing differences in the behaviors of unary operators that 99% of people will only ever use on numbers are not what I would call "basic." I don't think anyone should (or would ever need to) use the `-bareword` to `'bareword'` conversion in any practical situation.

Comment: If that's the case the questioner should be slapped upside the head. That's not "the basics." It's a trick question and not even one that reveals any useful functionality. Even if he was referring to the -g filetest operator I wouldn't consider that "basic."

Comment: I agree in both cases, but that's the only answer I can figure out (other than the -g filetest.)

Comment: B::Deparse will show what Perl thinks it is.  It's not `if('-G')`, its `if(-'G')` which happens to be true.  Anyhow, Michael is right.  "-g" certainly isn't "basic".  I don't think I've ever used it and I don't know why anyone would memorize it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no switch -G in perl.

perl -G
Unrecognized switch: -G  (-h will show valid options).

Edit: OK, there's nothing with -G either - only -g.

-g  File has setgid bit set.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html

Otherwise, it's nonsense and the question is misphrased.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about -G but -g is described [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) as

```
-g  File has setgid bit set.
```

Comment: I thought this at first, but I'm not sure that this is what he's talking about. Especially since the code `if(-G) {` produces no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly confusion between [ (test) options and Perl -X file tests.  -G is in the former (on my BSD system), but not the latter.  -G is a non-posix extension and I guess Perl didn't include all the extensions, just some.  So its either, he meant to say -g or he meant [ -G $file ]; (for some superset of POSIX [).  It is also in my default shell (pdksh) and bash (the linux default shell, for the most part)

-G in test or as a shell builtin here:

-G file
         True if file exists and its group matches the effective group ID
         of this process.

Answer (score 0):

One answer says: "I don't think anyone should (or would ever need to) use the -bareword to -'bareword' conversion in any practical situation."

This is widely used in one style of named parameters.  See the venerable [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) for one:

```
$cookie1 = $q->cookie(-name=>'riddle_name', -value=>"The Sphynx's Question");
$cookie2 = $q->cookie(-name=>'answers', -value=>\%answers);
print $q->header(
    -type    => 'image/gif',
    -expires => '+3d',
    -cookie  => [$cookie1,$cookie2]
);
```

Comment: The point of the -flag notation is that it doesn't confuse the bareword with a Perl built-in. -values doesn't confuse anything with values(%hash).

Comment: The leading dashes here seem like a stylistic carryover from command line switches. They aren't necessary; the fat comma quotes barewords on its left side.